# Show that for a set of vectors to be linearly independent in a subfield $F$ of a larger field $G$, they must be linearly independent in $G$.

Tags: linear-algebra

$F$ is a subfield of a larger field $G$.

Let $ v_1, v_2,\ldots,v_m $ be vectors in $F^n $. Show that $ v_1, v_2,\ldots,v_m $ are linearly independent in $ F^n $ $iff$ they are linearly independent in $G^n$.

Edit:

I know that if I extend this set of vectors to a basis of $F^n$ and form a square matrix, this matrix is invertible over $F$, hence it's also invertible over $G$ since $F^n \subset G^n$,

however I'm failing to work the way the question is asking me to.

Comment: What progress have you made?

Comment: Apologies, I've been working on another longer question and just came back to this one. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (direction 1): vectors in $F^n$ *are* vectors in $G^n$.

> If no set of coefficients chosen from $G$ gives a relation, picking from a subset of $G$ can't do so either.

Hint (direction 2):  $G$ has a basis and each of the $v_i \in F$ has a unique expansion in that basis.

> If there were a relation among the $v_i$ over $F$ there would be a relation (the same one) among their unique expansions over $G$.